# Kernel updates break NVIDIA drivers on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, 20.04, nvidia, kernel

I have a system with a GTX 1650 max-q running Ubuntu 20.04 and every time there's a kernel update, my laptop gets stuck at the manufacturer splash screen. After days of researching, I've figured out that the drivers need to be compiled against the new kernel each time the kernel is updated. I also found out that installing DKMS drivers should do this automatically, so that's what I've been trying to install but I keep running into snags. As of now, I've put a hold on kernel 5.13.0-30-generic to take a break and figure out what's going on. This is how I went about trying to install the DKMS drivers when I was running kernel 5.18.0-35-generic + NVIDIA 510 drivers this morning.

1. Boot into GRUB recovery for kernel 5.13.35-generic
2. Purge kernel 5.13.35-generic and headers

   **apt purge linux-image-5.13.35-generic
   apt purge linux-headers-5.13.35-generic**
3. Purge all nvidia packages and unused dependencies

   **apt purge nvidia***

   **apt autoremove**
4. Reboot into grub recovery for 5.13.30-generic (older kernel), enable networking, drop to root
5. Install 5.13.35-generic and headers

   **apt install linux-image-5.13.35-generic
   apt install linux-headers-5.13.35-generic**
6. Install nvidia dkms drivers + nvidia-settings + nvidia-utils

   **apt install nvidia-dkms-510 nvidia-settings nvidia-utils-510**
7. Reboot normally using the 5.13.35-generic kernel

Now once I reboot, I get a black screen with no GUI. From here, I can boot into tty and log in. Once I'm logging in, nvidia-smi spits out the correct info and everything seems to be working except for whatever reason, it won't boot into the GUI. Not sure what I'm doing wrong so any help would be appreciated. I've currently purged the 35 kernel completely and set the 30 as the default and put it on hold until I can figure this out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Nmath Perhaps, I apologize it's actually kernel 5.13 which I got through software updates.

Comment: @Nmath No, the Nvidia driver was installed during the OS installation process. Afterward I got an update for the new kernel in software updates so I went ahead and installed it. After installation I got stuck at the splash screen on boot. The only way to boot was to use the older kernel, presumably because the Nvidia driver needs to be recompiled against the new kernel from what I understand (could be wrong). I just don't know how to go about this correctly.

Comment: @Nmath Sorry, I'll update with the commands I've run. I can say, however, that this has happened to me several times and I usually stick with the NVIDIA driver that installs when the OS is originally installed. Kernel updates are only ever done when they show up in software update. I appreciate you taking the time to reply, I'll update my post.

Comment: @Nmath Updated to include all commands used.

Comment: You might consider using an older, more stable version of the Nvidia driver rather than hold back the kernel update. Especially since the Ubuntu community doesn't develop the proprietary Nvidia driver, sometimes it's better to stick with a more stable version.  Depending on how new your other hardware is, you might also consider researching how to switch to the GA kernel stack which is fixed on 5.4 for the life of 20.04. Switching to the GA kernel is preferable to holding back kernel updates when using the HWE kernel, which you are using if you're on 5.13

Comment: You can change the Nvidia driver in use in the software center settings, so you don't have to use any commands or manually install any other software.  There should be a choice of a few different Nvidia proprietary drivers.

Comment: @Nmath Thanks for taking the time to reply again, I really do appreciate it. So changing the drivers in the "additional drivers" section also yeilds the same outcome, computer get's stuck at the manufacturer boot screen. Each time the NVIDIA driver is changed, it needs to be compiled against the kernel. The DKMS drivers solve this problem but I'm not sure what I did wrong when attempting to install them. I'll look into how to switch to the GA kernel stack, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I have HWE kernel, Nvidia drivers 390 (these were selected for my card during OS installation, I have NVS 315) and no issues during kernel updates. Correct new versions of the Nvidia drivers are installed together with the kernel.

Comment: @raj Not sure what is going on then, but this happens to me with EVERY install of Ubuntu. I re installed my OS since posting here and the NVIDIA driver / kernel combo that wasn't working before works now as I installed the driver during the OS install. I just got an update notification for the 37-generic kernel and I'm going to have to hold off because I know it will break my drivers and I don't know how to fix this. I'm at a loss here.

Comment: This is what I got just today in my notifications: http://rafa.eu.org/share/public/Zrzut%20ekranu%20z%202022-03-22%2011-30-50.png . Note that nvidia drivers and nvidia kernel modules get installed together with the new kernel. Does it look different for you?

Comment: @raj Looks the same, but this WILL break my install.